# Proof Verification, extend $\varphi(x^n)=\varphi(x)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ to all integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, induction, group-isomorphism

Let $P(n)$ be the statement

''$\varphi(x^{-n})=\varphi(x)^{-n}$, ''

and let $\varphi$ be a homomorphism. Consider 
$P(1)$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
    \varphi(x^{-1})=\varphi(x)^{-1} 
\end{align*}
since homomorphisms map inverses to inverses. Suppose 
$P(k)$ is true for all $k\geq 1$. Observe that 
\begin{align*}
    \varphi(x^{-k-1})= \varphi(x^{-k}x^{-1})=
    \varphi(x^{-k})\varphi(x^{-1})=\varphi(x)^{-k}
    \varphi(x)^{-1}=\varphi(x)^{-k-1},
\end{align*}

therefore $P(k+1)$ holds. By the principal of mathematical 
induction, $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

I am unsure if this is a valid way to extend the theorem in the title to all integers. I don't think I have violated the principal of induction since I am still only dealing with positive integers in my statement $P(n)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could also use $y^{-n}=(y^{-1})^n$ for both $x$ and $\phi(x)$.

Comment: Aside from that, I haven't violated anything as far as induction goes?

Comment: Oh, $\varphi$ is a homomorphism. Would be better to lead with that information.

Comment: Good call. I added that to the first line.

Comment: looks good to me, although I think using induction here is a heavy overkill.

Comment: How would you suggest proving it?